T-SQL - Search for indexes with the following props configuration
Anyone know how to query the list of SQL Server indexes with the following index property settings?
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON
DROP_EXISTING = ON
RESUMABLE = ON 
ONLINE = ON
MAX_DURATION > 0 mins 
MAXDOP <> 0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax-for-sql-server-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-managed-instance
Found another thread that helps with such queries, but not seeing anything that points to where these props are stored (not really looking for feedback on whether the combination of these settings are good/bad/etc).
List of all index & index columns in SQL Server DB

These aren't properties of the index. They are directives for a specific operation

Some of those settings are for creation of indexes, they have no effect after the index is persisted. As usual, what are you really trying to figure out?

I want to write original create-statements of existing indexes before dropping them so I can re-run the same index definition later when needed. Makes sense for these settings to be only applicable during run-time.. is there any of them I can query?

Why do you want to drop them? I'd say, just run the indexes normally, although if you have ONLINE available, i'd probably include it (it's an enterprise feature me thinks)

When changing data-masking on indexes fields, we need to drop/create indexes. Trying to do it programmatically.

OK, then i'd probably figure out which of the above settings could benefit your system and use them. Most aren't needed though unless your tables are really large
